# LaTeX equivalent to MahtML's &ApplyFunction;

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators, brackets

Here is a question that has long been bothering me: what is the correct way to write a function application in \LaTeX?

The simple answer is of course `$f(x)$`. However, `$f\left(x\right)$` delivers a different result (in terms of spacing), even if the height of the argument does not require larger brackets.

In MathML, `&ApplyFunction;` controls the spacing between the function and its argument like so `<mi>f</mi><mo>&ApplyFunction;</mo><mfenced<mi>x</mi></mfenced>`.

Is there a similar construct in LaTeX?

Thanks,
Sébastien

Comment: I think the `mathtools` package fixes the spacing discrepancy between `f(x)` and `f\left(x\right)`, but I can't find a reference right now.

Comment: @ArunDebray, mathtools does not help in this case. If you insist on using left/right (I would not) then you need `\mleft/mright` (mleftright package). That case that mathtools does fix, is when a fencing macro is made using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter ` then the auto scaller is "fixed", but that is not general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `\!`, this is a negative space exactly equal to the extra space that is inserted between `f` and `\left(`. If necessary also at the end.

```
$f\!\left(x\right)\!$
```